# Using third condition of Pumping Lemma to simplify proof

Tags: pumping-lemma

So I've got a homework question that asks to prove that A = {a^n b^n c^n | n >= 0} is non-regular using the pumping lemma. From my textbook:

> To use the pumping lemma to prove that a language B is not regular, first assume that B is >regular in order to obtain a contradiction. Then use the pumping lemma to guarantee the >existence of a pumping length p such that all strings of length p or greater in B can be >pumped. Next, find a string s in B that has p or greater but that cannot be pumped. >Finally, demonstrate that s cannot be pumped by considering all ways of dividing s into x, >y, and z (taking condition 3 of the pumping lemma into account if convenient) and, for >each such division, finding a value i where xy^iz is not in B. This final step often >involves grouping the various ways of dividing s into several cases and analyzing them >individually.

From this, and from what my professor said in lecture, it seems to me that condition 3 can be used to prove B is not regular without the final step of considering the different groupings of xyz. That said, I cannot figure out how to do it.

For my proof I consider s = a^p b^p c^p for pumping length p. Given this, s is longer than the pumping length, and can be pumped. The third condition of the pumping lemma says that the length of xy <= p. For the most obvious grouping, where p consists only of b's, y is going to be of length p, so xy will violate condition 3, since x is also length p.

However, and this is where I am confused, it does not seem to me that this proves s cannot be pumped. It is still necessary to consider different groupings of xyz to show that there does not exist a grouping in which condition 3 is satisfied.

So I understand why A is not regular, and I can prove it. But it seems to me that I am missing something about how condition 3 can be applied to simplify the proof, and am attempting to understand this more fully.

Comment: This sounds like a question that belongs on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/).  Stackoverflow is for computer programming questions.  Is this a question that's related to algorithms or data structures?  Then maybe it belongs here, but you still might get more help on math.SE--I don't know.

Comment: It's more theory of computation. Maybe I should have posted it elsewhere regardless, but I think I've solved my own problem.

Comment: There seem to be no end of similar questions regarding the pumping lemma, though that doesn't necessarily mean they're in the correct place either.

Comment: Well, lots of similar questions is a good sign.  I should have checked that.  But for theory of computation, maybe my last remark still applies.  (I once was invited to interview for a job as a network administrator for a CS department at a top university.  I said, "Gee, I feel as if all of the people using the network will know more about networks and computers than I do.  The interviewer said, oh, don't worry about that.  Some of the professors don't really know anything about programming.  They just work on theoretical computer science.)

Comment: Yup. There's a chance it would fit in either. CS rests on top of quite a bit of mathematical theory, so I don't think you can always differentiate. There's quite a bit of stuff that falls under computer science that doesn't involve a computer. I think you may be right though, if stackoverflow is specifically for programming, the theory should go elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out. The piece I was missing was using condition 3 to restrict my choices of groupings.

Using the same word choice as above, s = a^p b^p c^p:
By condition 3 y must consist only of a's. Since there are p a's in s, including any number of b's will result in y > p, in which case xy > p as well. Now we pump:
For any value of i not equal to 1, there are an unequal number of a's, b's, and c's. Thus, s cannot be pumped for any valid choice of y.